# rails 3 validation for a comma-separated list of email addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

I'm a total newbie at Rails validation, and while I've seen some related questions, I cannot figure how to extend them to my situation.

I need to allow a user setting up their account to enter up to N (a system wide constant, like 10) optional email addresses.

so the data a user would enter into the text field might look like

```
foo@bar.com
```

or

```
foo@bar.com, foo2@bar2.com,foo3@bar3.com , foobar4@domain.com
```

(note inconsistent use of space before or after comma, typical real-user stuff)

currently in my model I handle single optional email and use a regex :

```
validates :alert_email,
    :allow_blank => true,
    :length => {:minimum => 3, :maximum => 254},
    :format => {:with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i}
```

There is probably some sort of uber-regex that I could replace mine with... and that would be fine if anyone can help. However for readability (and because performance is irrelevant since this is done once per user) I think I should somehow move the validation to a method that brute force parses them out and runs the regex one at a time?

PS I would also like my validation routine to "fix up" the space/comma thing, so it's always comma-space between items in the list, and have that fixed-up version be what's saved. I'm guessing I do some before_xxxxx method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Ruby `split` method to separate your list of emails into an array and the join method to save them back into a common format.

```
before_validation do
  emails = self.emails.split(/\s+,\s+/)

  emails.each do |email|
    self.errors.add(:emails, "invalid email") unless email =~ /([^\s]+)@([^\s]+)/ 
  end

  self.emails = emails.join(",")
end
```

Comment: Parsing this inside the model like this is a surefire way to introduce bugs. Eg. your example breaks when the field is already an array.

Comment: I suspect jdeseno's comment is correct technically, however, in my particular simple app and ui case, it looks like this might be the simplest and easiest route for a relative newbie such as myself.

Comment: emails = self.emails.strip.downcase.split(/[\s,]+/) --- #this worked better for me

Comment: hey what is value there? and emails are your variable or field name?

Comment: @SSR - It's a typo. `value` should be `email`

Answer (score 2):

In your form you can submit a collection of values if you use a format like this:

```
&optional_email[]=email1@example.com&optional_email[]=email2@example.com
```

You would represent this in your form like:

```
Email 1: <%= text_field_tag 'optional_email[]' %>
Email 2: <%= text_field_tag 'optional_email[]' %>
```

These also work with the model helpers etc.

Then rails will figure out how to turn those parameters into a collection like:

```
params[:optional_email] = ['email1@example.com', 'email2@example.com']
```

If you can't do that, an alternative would be splitting this yourself inside your controller:

```
@model.optional_emails = params[:optional_email].split(/[\,]/).map(&:strip)
```

Then in either case you can write a validation that works on each individual email without using a huge regex.

Depending how your data is being used you may be better served with a model for emails. If you have a reason not to do that you could use the `serialize` method on your model to ensure this field is always a collection of emails.

Comment: Hi, thanks, although I don't quite understand your answer... we need users to be able to enter the delimited string of emails into a text field... it's not really practical to ask users to also type &optional_email... or put another way, we could ask but then we still have to handle cases where they do it wrong...

Comment: Sorry, that is the format that the form is submitting parameters with. Edited with an example of how you'd do that from a form helper.

Comment: Ah, I see now what you meant, thanks. That's probably the "right" way to do it... but in our case for a couple of reasons we really do have to let them enter the list into a single field... large because there can be up to 10 and 10 fields takes up too much space on the screen whereas a single field can scroll sideways to accept quite a long string.

Comment: Edited with an example of how you could make that a little easier in your controller. The original idea of treating this as a collection and writing a validation for that is unchanged.

Comment: That last example i sone I want to play with and see if I can get it figured out. Thanks for your considerable help!

Answer (score 1):

```
validates :daily_recipients,
   :format => { :with => /(\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})(,\s*([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,}))*\z)/i },
   :allow_blank => true
```

Comment: Maybe you want to explain your code a little more?

Answer (score 0):

By keeping all of those email addresses in a single field you are losing a lot of the power of Rails. There are oodles of methods that help with set operations, finding, validating, associating, etc., that you will miss out on or have to implement yourself. This question is just an example of that. The rails way to do this is to create a separate model for these emails, store them there one record per email, and associate that model with your Account model.

Comment: I don't disagree... except for this UI I need to gather the input into a single field, and in the past I've had nothing but trouble trying to manage a variable-number of associated fields.